# Extract data from two different tags in a multiline XML

Tags: xml, sed

I have a sample XML like:

```
<soap:Body
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<GetRooms_V2Response
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <GetRooms>
    <Allocations>
        <AllocationID>426231</AllocationID>
        <AllocationName>Edinburgh Carlton Hotel</AllocationName>
        <ValidFrom>2014-11-01T00:00:00</ValidFrom>
        <ValidTo>2020-12-31T00:00:00</ValidTo>
        <RoomTypes>Double Room</RoomTypes>
        <BookingType>1</BookingType>
        <PriceType>523</PriceType>
        <IsBar>true</IsBar>
        <Days> … (details omitted due to size)
    </Allocations>
    <Allocations>
```

I want to extract data between `AllocationID.../AllocationID`
and `RoomTypes.../RoomTypes`. I do not want a multiline script because I will be grepping a few more things before inputting this data.

I tried something like this but it reads only single tag at a time:

```
sed -n 's:.*AllocationID\(.*\)/AllocationID.*:\1:p' test.xml
```

and this doesn't work:

```
sed -n 's:.*AllocationID\(.*\)/AllocationID.*\RoomTypes\(.*\)</RoomTypes).*:\1,\2:p' test.xml
```

Can anyone please explain what's the best way to do this?

Comment: You could use XSLT instead of sed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This extracts what you need:

```
sed -nE 's/(<AllocationID>(.*)<.*|<RoomTypes>(.*)<.*)/\2\3/gp' test.xml
```

I doubled your file.
Output:

```
426231
Double Room
426231
Double Room
```

Comment: Thanks for this fix. This works perfectly with the snippet I had provided. But for some bizarre reason, I just realised that in my logfile there are multiple xml lines and this grep doesn't parse xml lines as one line. So now I first need to figure out if I should first concatenate all the xml lines in the log file into a one single xml and then apply egrep or there is some better way to do it